# How to modify several nested elements in BEM?

Tags: html, css, bem

Not BEM html and CSS:

```html
  <div class="item active">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="text">Step 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="text">Step 2</div>
  </div>
```

```css
.item {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .item .text {
    color: gray;
  }
  .item .square {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .item.active .text {
    color: red;
  }
  .item.active .square {
    border-color: red;
  }
```

In this case, to mark some item as active, I just add the class 'active' to parent tag.

BEM version:

```html
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__square item__square_active"></div>
    <div class="item__text item__text_active">Step 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__square"></div>
    <div class="item__text">Step 1</div>
  </div>
```

```css
.item {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .item__text {
    color: gray;
  }
  .item__square {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .item__text_active {
    color: red;
  }
  .item__square_active {
    border-color: red;
  }
```

In this case, I have to add two classes item__text_active and item__square_active to appropriate child elements. And It looks awkward.

Questions: is the BEM approach implemented correctly? Is there a way to use one modifier for a block that will change the styles of nested elements?

Answer (score 0):

Get answer from forum(https://ru.bem.info/forum/1608/): A cascade from a block modifier to elements is permissible (for example, for theming)

```html
<div class="item item_active">
  <div class="item__square"></div>
  <div class="item__text">Step 1</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__square"></div>
  <div class="item__text">Step 1</div>
</div>
```

```css
.item__text {
    color: gray;
  }
  .item__square {
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
  .item_active .item__text {
    color: red;
  }
  .item_active .item__square {
    border-color: red;
  }
```